# Rails - Cocoon - Simple Form - does not render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, cocoon-gem

I'm using Cocoon and SimpleForm for new Orders, which will have multiple OrderItems.

I've installed the gem like so :

```
gem "cocoon"
```

And also add to application.js :

```
//= require cocoon
```

Models are configured like so :

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

#Associations
has_many :order_items
accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_items, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end


class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base

#Associations
belongs_to :order
belongs_to :item
end
```

_form.html.slim for Orders is :

```
= simple_form_for(@order) do |f|
   = f.error_notification
   .row
    .col-md-6
        .form-inputs
            = f.association :branch
            = f.association :client

    .col-md-6
        = f.simple_fields_for :order_items do |order_item|
            = render 'order_item_fields', f: order_item
            .links
                = link_to_add_association 'add order_item', f, :order_items

.form-actions
= f.button :submit
```

and the partial _order_items_fields.html.slim is :

```
.nested_fields
  = f.input :item_id
  = f.input :dicount_percentage
  = f.input :fulfilment_type
  = f.input :promised_delivery_date
  = f.input :actual_delivery_date
  = f.input :notes
  = link_to_remove_association "remove order item", f
```

When I run orders/new, all the fields are displayed except the ones that should be displayed by cocoon.

I've done everything by the instructions on the github page.

What could the problem be?

I've also checked and the cocoon JS file is being loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about HAML, but I believe that you need to line up the `.links` with `= f.simple_fields_for :order_items do |order_item|` since HAML is whitespace dependent.

Using [this simple form example](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon_simple_form_demo/blob/master/app/views/projects/_form.html.slim#L21) linked to from the Cocoon github

Comment: how careless of me! Thank you so much for spotting that!

Answer (score 0):

Your form is empty because your fields should be nested under `simple_form`

```
= simple_form_for(@order) do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  .row
    .col-md-6
      .form-inputs
        = f.association :branch
        = f.association :client
```

Comment: Apologies, they are already nested, I've corrected the question now. Is everything alright now?